# Cannot restore postgres dump file

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

When i try to restore a database from a dump file using the following command:

```
 \i C:/pathname/dumpfile.txt
```

from within my sql shell, it runs the first few lines of the dump file and then I get the following error:

> ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.databasename"
>   DETAIL:  System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.

This shows the beginning of the dump file. I think the `CREATE TABLE` command triggers the error.

[image]

I'm using postgreSQL Version 11.1. 
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you created an empty schema for your data? Maybe you could try that?

Comment: But then how do I restore the dump into this empty schema?

Comment: Do you still have access to the old database?  if so, redo the dump using the pg_dump from 11.1, not from 9.6.0.

Comment: Unless you changed the setting of "log_min_error_statement", you shouldn't have to guess what statement triggered the ERROR.  The ERROR message will include the triggering statement.  Using the default log format, it will be flagged with "STATEMENT:"

Comment: I don't have access to the old database so I can't redo the dump. I tried to restore it using Version 9.6.0 though, but that didn't work either.

Comment: When I have had this problem in the past, I try and break it into simpler components. First, create your individual tables - taking account of `FOREIGN KEY`s. Then, load the data, table by table. You **may** discover errors here along the way... Then, hopefully, when you've done it manually once, you can automate the process to your satisfaction!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it: in the following line:

```
SET search_path = car, pg_catalog;
```

apparantly, car is the name of the schema. As that schema didn't exist, it tried to create a table in the pg_catalog schema. I manually created a schema called car, and, tada..
Thanks to everybody for their support.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you need to set the search_path (see the other answer to the question).

```
SET search_path = car, pg_catalog;
```

Then check if the schema exists. If not, then add this to your SQL dump file:

```
CREATE SCHEMA car;
ALTER SCHEMA car OWNER TO car;
```